# Different behavior System.Uri

Tags: c#, wpf, rest

I'm newbie to .Net especially 4.5 version.

I have written library which use class `System.Uri` object.
when I invoke code:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://myUrl/%2F");
```

in console application it create new Uri object with AbsoluteUri set to

```
"http://myurl/%2F",
```

but when I invoke the same code in web service application AbsoluteUri  is set to

```
"http://myurl//"
```

How can I use "%2f" without conversion in server aplication

Comment: try with  `http://myUrl/%252F`

Comment: %2F is `/` sow what is the actual prolem (use-case) ?  @Damith - how is that the same?

Comment: I try to use [rabbitMQ](http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/%2f/my-new-exchange) eq.  http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/%2f/my-new-exchange

Answer (score 1):

`%2f` convert to `/`

try with

```
http://myurl/%252F
```

`%25` is equal to `%` then %252F will convert to %2F at server side, as you expected

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://myUrl/%252F");
uri.LocalPath //  "/%2F"
```